# PHP: Radiobutton visible and hide the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a question regards to PHP about "radiobutton".Today, I'm trying to code a radiobutton where when I choose the radiobutton1 the button submit should be visible but then when I choose the radiobutton2 the button submit should be invisible.

My Problem is:

I want to invisible the button submit when I click the radiobutton2 and then when I click the radiobutton1 the button submit should be visible. I'm trying to do the code without using form action. And I'm already search about this but its all about with form action.

Below is my codes:

```
<html>
<body>
<Input type = 'Radio' name ='con' value= 'sample'>SAmple:
<Input type = 'Radio' name ='con' value= 'other'>Others:

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the serverside language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript here. Change your HTML to this

```
  <html>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
   function show_but()
  {
         jQuery('#span_submit').show();
  }
  function hide_but()
  {
       jQuery('#span_submit').hide();
  }

 <script>
 <body>
   <Input type = 'Radio' name ='con' value= 'sample' onclick="show_but();">SAmple:

   <Input type = 'Radio' name ='con' value= 'other' onclick="hide_but();">Others:
  <span id="span_submit">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
  </span> 
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: it Works!. Thank you so much for helping me to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=con]').change(function(){
        if($('input[name=con]:checked').val() == 'sample'){
            $('input[name=submit]').show();
        } else {
            $('input[name=submit]').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and helping. I'm also newbie in jquery..How can I apply it to the radibutton? I already paste it in my code but it not work...Sorry I'm really really newbie in jquery and php..Hope you can still help me.

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library? See my edit for how to include it

Comment: Oooppss...Sorry...My first time to tuse jquery.. but its already works! thanks for the reply and helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing you can do with PHP. This is JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: Oh i see.. Can you help me how to do it in JAvascript or jQuery? Thanks for the reply

Answer (score -1):

Check whole working code -

```
<html>
<body>
<Input type = 'Radio' name ='con' value= 'sample'>SAmple:
<Input type = 'Radio' name ='con' value= 'other'>Others:

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none;">  

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
//jQuery('input[name=submit]').hide();
jQuery('input[name=con]').on('change',function(){
    if(jQuery(this).val() == 'sample')
        jQuery('input[name=submit]').show();
    else
        jQuery('input[name=submit]').hide();
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also use `on` method, like this -

```
jQuery('input[name=con]').on('change',function(){
```

Comment: @PhilistyneBrigidBellisima lol its ok ..best of luck with the coding part :)

Comment: Thanks Again swapnesh! :) and btw, I cant downvoted or vote because of my reputation :D

Comment: Hey @swapnesh are u still der?

Comment: @PhilistyneBrigidBellisima yeah ..tell

Comment: thanks! i have another question...How can I invisible the button on load when I run file? Upon loading the button is already hide...

Comment: ! thanks so much for helping me!...I can sleep well today :) and sorry so many question I'm really newbie in php and jquery

Comment: @Philistyne Brigid Bellisima  ahh no problem..u can ping me anytime or mail me in my inbox